# LinkButton Clicked OnPreRender

Tags: asp.net, controls, linkbutton, asplinkbutton

I Have a `LinkButton` when clicked I want to preform an operation inside the `OnPreRender` method.

So how would I know if that `LinkButton` was clicked?

Say my LinkButton's name is `lnkbtn1`.

Thanks in advance.

Baher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button's Clicked event would already have been called by the time you get to PreRender, so maybe use the Click event to set a private boolean property on your control to indicate whether the button was clicked, which you can then check later in PreRender.